# Data shared between different users and requests in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, react-state-management

I do not know how to ask this question more formally. I was looking for state management in React while using Next.js, for example redux or react-query. I have seen a lot of comments that say something along the lines:

> Be careful to NOT do that because the users of your application will share the same state

I do not fully understand what this means and how to actually implement something like this to grasp why and how is happening.

So is there a minimal example where you set a state management "the wrong way" and different users can access the state of other users ?

Comment: Hi @entropyfeverone can you provide links to where you see these types of comments. I can say that a default state management setup (redux or similar) does not have this kind of effect. To able to share state like this it would have to come from the server.

Comment: @AndresZapata Yes it's about Server Side Rendering. It's been some time since I have read these kind of comment but I will try to find them and add them as a reference to my original post.

Comment: It's a fact that state can be shared, for example jotai acknowledges this fact in their docs:
https://jotai.org/docs/guides/nextjs#provider

Answer (score 0):

If you store your data in a regular variable in your module, those will get shared between requests. Next.js is based on Node.js and all the data in the single thread is shared. The problem is age-old. [Read more in vercel/nextjs issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/8588)